# Javascript function on jQuery dialog close

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a jQuery dialog box. This box launches when a link is clicked. This link launches a function that loads the textfields within the dialog box. I have another function that is executed within the dialog load function. This looks through all of the objects and matches the table rows to the object clicked and sets a different class for that row. Now on exit i just need to do the same. How can I bind a function to the close event of that particular dialog? I just need to fire a javascript event everytime the dialog window is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Is this any use?

```
$('div#popup_content').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
     alert('closed');
 });
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event to the beforeClose or close event of the jquery dialog box

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) { ... }
});

$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-close

Comment: I honestly cannot figure this out. I have a function that I use around my application to open my dialog 'function showDialog(id) { $(id).dialog("open"); } but I cannot get this to work:  $(<%= this.updateStatus.ClientID %>).dialog({
            close: function(event, ui) {
                alert("BANG!");
            }
        }); ' Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, looks like I have to bind the close function to my custom objects. I have created a custom control that will contain the jquery dialog box as well as a custom control for each button needed.

Comment: Have you got it figured out? If you post some sample code I could give a more definitive answer