# Dispose Java Applet After closing a DIalog

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, applet, jquery-ui-dialog, japplet

Is there anyway to dispose Java Applet after closing Jquery UI dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the event `dialogclose` and then append your applet in the callback:

```
$("#dialog").bind("dialogclose", function() {
    // make applet and append to body
});
```

[Hook into dialog close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event)

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I need the javascript code to kill or dispose Java Applet