# Trigger refocus tab action once modal window is open

Tags: jquery

How to you trigger a tab to open once the close button on a modal dialog is opened? This is the code I have so far and it only presents me with a the error message in plain text.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );}}
    });
$("#tabs").tabs("select",1);
    return false;
        });
});
</script>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Incorrect password">
    The password you have provided is incorrect.<br>Please try again.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified from [Hook into dialog close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event)

```
 $('div#dialog-message').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select",1);
 });
```

Or try this:

```
$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function(){
        $("#tabs").tabs("select",1);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I have so far, it doesn't seem to be working: http://pastebin.com/vLA3deQW

Comment: Updated with another option.  Make sure you aren't getting errors in your console.