# pop up window not closing

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

I have a popup window which should close during submit.But it is not closing but data is adding in grid. The script used is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        height : 400,
        width : 700,
        modal : true,
        title: "Currency Details",
        close : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    });

});
```

And this is my ajaxsubmit

```
function saveCurrencyAjax() {
        var str = $("#enumCurrency").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "../currency/saveEnumCurrency.action",
            data : str,
            success : function(response) {
                $('#dialog-form').dialog('close');

            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    };
```

This is my controller

```
  @RequestMapping( value="/currency/saveEnumCurrency.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView saveenumCurrency(@ModelAttribute EnumCurrency enumCurrency, Errors errors) throws Exception {   

            ModelAndView mvc = null;
            try{
                List<EnumCurrency> enumCurrencys =  new ArrayList<EnumCurrency>();
                enumCurrencys.add(enumCurrency);
                List<EnumCurrency> enumCurrencysList = enumCurrencyService.create(enumCurrencys);
                mvc =   new ModelAndView("setup/enumCurrencyList");


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mvc; 
        }
```

Thanks in advance, if need more information inform me.

Comment: Did you try an alert or console.log in the success callback to ensure it was being run?

Comment: Ya i tried.Its comming to saveCurrencyAjax().

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do this:
 `success : function(response) { alert('success called')`

Do you see the alert?

Comment: yaa it is showing alert message success call. Actually my problem is after submitting data is adding into the grid (after refreshing) but the pop window is not closing.

Comment: The syntax of the function you are using to close it doesn't make very much sense to me. It seems like it ought to be `dialog.close()`

Answer (score 0):

First Confirm that whether its coming to success Function ! and try this

```
$('div#popup_content').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
     alert('closed');
 });
```

refer - [Accepted Answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event)

Just Try