# Call function if jQuery dialog is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery UI to show a dialog, but I don't know how to call a function if dialog is closed by user. This is the code:

```
    function Configure_Popup() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 100
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "blind",
                duration: 100
            }
        });

        $(".opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    }
```

How can I do that please?

Comment: So what is not working? Looks like you have the code that opens it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) event:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 100
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 100
    },
    close: function() {
        console.log("User closed the dialog");
        // Call your function here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank's for your help