# Angularjs how to reset form when close JQuery dialog

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have different dialog boxes in a page. if i open dialog box and do some form submit if the form is not a valid then it will show error messages and the dialog is closing. again if I reopen the same dialog errors are showing. i want to hide error messages when i reopen the same dialog again.

I have done some code changes in dialog close event it's not working.

```
$dlg = $("#ItemDialog");

close: function () {
    var popupForm = $dlg.find("form");
    $(popupForm).trigger('reset');
    if ($scope.popupForm) $scope.popupForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Comment: tip: don't use angular and jQuery together, they overlap and angular (for the most part makes jQuery obsolete) if you use it right

Comment: My current project is in JQuery and Live Project, now started implementing AngularJs so we cannot break existing JQuery functionality, so can you please give me a solution for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like close event is not binding correctly. To bind close event of jquery dialog see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/172000/2509344

**EDIT**
To clear form try this:

```
var popupForm = $dlg.find("form");
popupForm[0].reset();
```

or if you don't have radio, checkbox and select try this

```
popupForm.find("input, textarea").not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]').val("");
```

Comment: when i debug through chrome close event is working fine.

Comment: it's working fine, the second solution you have given it's emptying the button value also.

Comment: @RajeshGK Fixed second solution too